# VBA: Download a file

Tags: excel, file, vba, download

I'm trying to download an Excel file from the internet and then extract data out of it. The problem is that I don't get any errors, yet the file downloaded is only 1kb in size. The extraction bit works, but the file is empty. The actual file is size 350KB.

```
    Sub ExtractDataTest()

    Dim FileNum As Long
    Dim FileData() As Byte
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim WHTTP As Object

    On Error Resume Next
        Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    MyFile = "http://enhanced1.sharepoint.hs.com/teams/"

    WHTTP.Open "GET", MyFile, False
    WHTTP.Send
    FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody
    Set WHTTP = Nothing

    If Dir("C:\xampp\htdocs\test", vbDirectory) = Empty Then MsgBox "No folder exist"

    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open "C:\xampp\htdocs\test\DE_TrackingSheet.xlsx" For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
        Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
    Close #FileNum

    Dim FilePath$, Row&, Column&, Address$

 'change constants & FilePath below to suit
     '***************************************
    Const FileName$ = "DE_TrackingSheet.xlsx"
    Const SheetName$ = "Open"
    Const NumRows& = 50
    Const NumColumns& = 20
    FilePath = ("C:\xampp\htdocs\test\")
     '***************************************

    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     If Dir(FilePath & FileName) = Empty Then
        MsgBox "The file " & FileName & " was not found", , "File Doesn't Exist"
        Exit Sub
        End If
    For Row = 1 To NumRows
        For Column = 1 To NumColumns
            Address = Cells(Row, Column).Address
            Cells(Row, Column) = GetData(FilePath, FileName, SheetName, Address)
            Columns.AutoFit
        Next Column
    Next Row
    ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False
End Sub


Private Function GetData(Path, File, Sheet, Address)
    Dim Data$
    Data = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & _
    Range(Address).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    GetData = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Data)
End Function
```

Comment: i ran across this same issue with FTP once, I know it seems trivial, but make sure your file name is completely accurate. That is what threw me off with my issue... it was something as simple as an extra space or something.

Comment: It's accurate. Also, if there was a misspelling I would get an error message, and would definitely not have a 1kb file in my folder.

Comment: Have you tried just using `WorkBooks.Open("http://pathhere")`. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably the fact the data is binary;

```
....
WHTTP.Open "GET", MyFile, False
WHTTP.Send

Set strm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With strm
    .Type = 1
    .Open
    .Write WHTTP.ResponseBody
    .SaveToFile "C:\null\df.xlsx", 2 '//2==overwrite
End With
Set WHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. What do you mean `the data is binary`?